# FAIL: Deploy MEAN.js app to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, web-deployment

I'm deploying my MEAN.js Node app to AWS.  Steps 1-4 are the commands I run from my local machine:

1) `grunt build` (DONE)

2) `git commit -m "production deployment"` my newly concatenated production files. (DONE)

3) Set `NODE_ENV=production`on AWS.  (DONE)

3) Set the AWS "NodeCommand" to `grunt`.  (DONE)

4) `git aws.push` (DONE)

At this point my deployment fails because the app is uploaded to my EC2 then `grunt` gets called but since grunt isn't install globally the app fails to start.

I've tried settings step 3 to `node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt`

Here is my package.json (which should install bower dependencies when app starts.. I think).

`},
{
  "name": "blah",
  "description": "blah",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "me",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.4.x"
  },
  "scripts": { <--------------------------------------------------- These scripts run?
    "start": "node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt",
    "test": "node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt test",
    "postinstall": "node_modules/bower/bin/bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.5",
    "express-session": "~1.8.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "compression": "~1.1.0",
    "method-override": "~2.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.3.2",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.4.1",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "helmet": "~0.4.0",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "swig": "~1.4.1",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.8",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "forever": "~0.11.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.8",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "glob": "~4.0.5",
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "nodemailer": "~1.3.0",
    "nodemailer-ses-transport": "~1.2.0",
    "nodemailer-dkim": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "supertest": "~0.14.0",
    "should": "~4.0.4",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.9.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.6.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.2"
  }
}`

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?